# Где удалить объект, созданный в отдельном потоке?

Tags: многопоточность, qt

создаю объект (производный от `QObject`) в отдельном потоке, чтобы он "жил" в нем, как и рекомендуют. На каждый поток создается с помощью new 1 объект. Поток завершается, объект надо удалить. Либо `delete this` в самом объекте, когда он завершает свою работу - уродливо! Либо из-вне, в объекте, который запустил поток, и знает, что объект из потока завершил свою работу, но не рекомендуют удалять объект не из потока, в котором создан.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/delete-this.html

Comment: А нельзя объекту выставить поток parent'ом? тогда при удалении потока он зачистит все объекты, у которых он родителем. Или у вас поток не через QTHRead?

Comment: @asianirish: А почему бы не «прибить» объект в конце threadproc? (Я не знаток QT, так что может быть это не так и легко.)

Comment: @VladD , может мы друг друга не поняли, я говорю не о наследовании от QThread, а о присвоении свойству потомков QObject parent ссылки на поток, в котором он живет, поток-QThread тоже получит ссылку на объект и при удалении запустит удаление всех своих "детей" (через QObjectList & QObject::children () насколько я понимаю, я сам qt не слишком хорошо знаю)

Comment: @aknew: А, вот как оно можно! Ну, выглядит ничего, беру своё замечание назад. Пусть знатоки QT прокомментируют.

Comment: а может классика? умные указатели или просто через deleteLater.

Comment: Доброго времени суток! Может я не прав, но насколько я понял из документации Qt можно использовать слот deleteLater() из-вне, т.е. в объекте, который запустил поток. Наподобие как в примере Threaded Fortune Server Example (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/threadedfortuneserver.html)

Comment: Должно натолкнуть на некоторые мысли
http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html
http://habrahabr.ru/post/167009/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleteLater не подойдет, если в потоке создается большое количество объектов, которые не будут удалятся, пока не перестанет жить поток, а до вся эта куча объектов будет занимать все больше и больше памяти, а потом сам процесс удаления будет занимать кучу процессорного времени, пока не удалит все. Умные указатели хорошее решение. В нестандартных случаях можно написать свой класс очистителя, живущий в том же потоке и уничтожающий объекты в процессе работы под контролем программиста, а уже сам такой объект удалять по deleteLater.

Comment: deleteLater не подойдет, если в потоке создается большое количество объектов, которые не будут удалятся, пока не перестанет жить поток,

все зависит от того, имеет ли поток свою очередь сообщений или нет. Если не имеет, то да, они удалятся в самом конце.